# It keeps giving me an error in http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler

Tags: android, eclipse

I get this msg as a popup always! nevermind the other problems now! I just have this problem!

Problem Occured

Unable to read repository at
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler

Unable to read repository at
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/201309270900/content.jar

Help

Comment: I can download that .jar file. May be firewall is blocking you.

Comment: I installed it while the firewall was off, another problem occured! "Errors occurred during the build.
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (839).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle."

Comment: And: Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (839).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (839).

Comment: try `https://..`  instead of 'http://'